# Why is it mandatory to make used variable in inner functions final?

Tags: java, final

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final AbcClass worker = new AbcClass() {

        @Override
        public void sayHello() {
            System.out.println("hello  ");

        }

    };
    JButton jButton = new JButton();
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            worker.sayHello();

        }
    });

}
```

Why the java compiler oblige me to put the worker object as a final?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: I don't think there's a reason, other than that Java sort of sucks. The compiler could make `worker` `final` implicitly, but it doesn't.